# Active record syntax in Yii for select from subquery

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

I have an SQL query, that works good, but I don't know how to write a correct criteria in Yii Active Record.

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `params`
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `job_queue` ORDER BY `time` ASC
) AS `job_ordered`
GROUP BY `type`;
```

Comment: I think that this isn't possible, because you can't set the from in a criteria. You can use CDbCommand to build this query, but then you can't pipe the data into a ActiveRecord...

Comment: Why do you group without any aggregation in your SQL? (That's unusual) ... and ... about ActiveRecord in Yii... have you generated any models for your tables yet?

Comment: I agree with @nazim. Your specific example seems like overkill. Why not just run `SELECT id, type, params FROM job_queue GROUP BY type ORDER BY time ASC`?

Comment: I think u can execute this query using `DAO Query Builder`. Did u tried it?